# Huxtable package : is it possible to use rowspan() with tidy verse syntax?

Tags: r, dplyr

I tried to use the `rowspan`function  with the `tidyverse` syntax, but I did not succeed.

Without piping it works without any problem:

```
library(huxtable)

HUX_table <- as_hux(HUX_table)                %>%
  huxtable::add_colnames()                    %>%
  set_top_border(1, everywhere, 1)            %>%
…    

rowspan(HUX_table)[2, 1] <- 3
rowspan(HUX_table)[5, 1] <- 3
rowspan(HUX_table)[8, 1] <- 3
```

Is it possible to use rowspan() among the piping calls, and if, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me (added some code to make this a MCVE, and put all the borders in to make output clearer):

```
  library(huxtable)
  library(dplyr)
  HUX_table <- matrix("x", 10, 2)
  HUX_table <- as_hux(HUX_table)            %>%
        huxtable::add_colnames()            %>%
        set_all_borders(1)    %>%
        set_rowspan(c(2, 5, 8), 1, 3)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Code-only answers are discouraged, as they provide no insight as to how the problem was solved. Please update your answer to include an explanation of how your code solves the OP's problem :)

Comment: Thanks a lot David! Thanks to the example now easy to follow the syntax of huxtable, i.e. set_rowspan(ROWs, COLs, NumRowsToSpan). So here cells in "Rows: 2, 5, 8" and in "Column 1": span across "3" cells